# Passing variables to email template in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi forget about all that, I see the logic how that won't work. Updated question;

How would I define in my controller to run and do the following when the Class is fetched in URL;

1) I need to find all "jobs" to current_user
I'm guessing something like this;

```
@joblisting = current_user.Joblisting.find(params[:id)
```

2) Then I need to take those jobs and check if their column "job_status" has the text "completed" in them or other"

3) If the jobs_status is "completed" then I need to run code so I do an "if"

4) I would have to pass the calculation.

```
@joblisting = current_user.Joblisting.find(params[:id]
   if @joblisting.where(:project_status => "completed")
      number_to_currency(current_user.Joblisting.where(:project_status => 'completed').sum('jobprice') * 1.60 - current_user.Joblisting.where(:project_status => 'completed').sum('jobprice'))
      Notifier.notify_payout(current_user).deliver
      @joblisting.project_status = 'paid'
      @joblisting.save
end
```

This is what I've got and I'm stuck with passing the calculation to the Notifier.notify_payout template.

I'm sure whomever knows rails better then me, will right away see my mistakes.

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be from this code, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: 1) Please create a temporary variable. 2) Is the variable really named `Joblisting`, where convention would use `joblisting`? 3) Stay consistent; use `sum(:jobprice)` instead of a string to identify the column.

Comment: I think you should calculate this amount earned somewhere else, not inside the view.

Comment: @MrYoshiji is correct, this is inappropriate code for a view

Comment: Like calculate it in the controller?? sorry newbie here.. would I just move it to something like this in the controller;

Comment: @payout = number_to_currency(@developer.Joblisting.where(:project_status => 'completed').sum('jobprice') * 1.60 - @developer.Joblisting.where(:project_status => 'completed').sum('jobprice'))

Comment: Just updated with a new question above to solve my overall issue.

Comment: @user1924165 The method `number_to_currency` is not available by default in the Controller. You can calculate the `@payout` in the Controller and then in the view: `number_to_currency(@payout)`

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thank you! I thought about that today. Glad I was close to very similar example.